# How to set ImageView setOnClickListner which is in custom listview and play/pause song when Imageview clicked?

Tags: android, custom-lists

I am new to android and i want to play and pause song when `ImageView` clicked.According to my project I have one custom listview and in this listview i have two `ImageView`.So,when user select play at that time play the song and select pause at that time pause the song.

**Note:-** Basically I want to set that onClickListner in my activity class not to custom listview adapter.And i am adding that songs from `res\raw` folder to arraylist.

**Here this my adapter**

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
private ArrayList<SongModel> songsListDat = null;
public ArrayList<SongModel> songsList;
private static LayoutInflater inflater;

public SongAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<SongModel> songsListDat) {

    this.context = activity;
    this.songsListDat = songsListDat;
    this.songsList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();
    this.songsList.addAll(songsListDat);
}
public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
{
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return songsListDat.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return songsListDat.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ringtone_row_layout, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // title
    ImageView play = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayPause);
    ImageView pause = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPause);


    SongModel song = new SongModel();
    song = songsListDat.get(position);
    title.setText(song.getSongTitle());

    return vi;
}
}
```

**This is activity class :-** In this activity i want set onclicklistner for play and pause functionality.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

public static final String TAG = "[MainActivity]";

Activity activity;
SongAdapter songAdapter;
SongsManager songsManager = new SongsManager();
MediaPlayer mp;

// Songs list
public ArrayList<SongModel> songsList = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    activity = MainActivity.this;


    mp = new MediaPlayer();


    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager(activity);
    final ArrayList<SongModel> songsListData = songsManager.songList;


    this.songsList = plm.getAllSongs();


    for (int i = 0; i < songsListData.size(); i++) {
        SongModel song = songsListData.get(i);
        songsListData.add(song);
    }


    songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songsList);
    setListAdapter(songAdapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
}
}
```

**and this is my song model class**

```
public class SongModel {

private String songPath, songTitle;

public SongModel(String songPath, String songTitle) {
    this.songPath = songPath;
    this.songTitle = songTitle;
}

public SongModel() {

}

public void setSongPath(String songPath){
    this.songPath = songPath;
}

public String getSongPath() {

    return songPath;
}
public void setSongTitle(String songTitle){
    this.songTitle = songTitle;
}

public String getSongTitle() {

    return songTitle;
}

}
```

If anyone know then please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Add a interface in your adapter class like & use it like this ::

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<SongModel> songsListDat = null;
    public ArrayList<SongModel> songsList;
    public OnMusicListener mListener;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SongAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<SongModel> songsListDat, OnMusicListener mListener) {

        this.context = activity;
        this.mListener = mListener;
        this.songsListDat = songsListDat;
        this.songsList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();
        this.songsList.addAll(songsListDat);
    }

    public void setSelectedIndex(int ind) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songsListDat.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return songsListDat.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ringtone_row_layout, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // title
        ImageView play = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayPause);
        ImageView pause = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPause);


        SongModel song = new SongModel();
        song = songsListDat.get(position);
        title.setText(song.getSongTitle());

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mListener.onPlayClicked(position);
            }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mListener.onPauseClicked(position);
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }

    public interface OnMusicListener {
        void onPauseClicked(int position);

        void onPlayClicked(int position);
    }
}
```

Then from your activity class

```
songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songsList,this);
setListAdapter(songAdapter);
```

After `"this "` added you can now implements the method from interface

from that you can have the click event of each play/pause of the list..

Please tell if needed more help..

So this will be your activity should like this ::

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements SongAdapter.OnMusicListener{

    public static final String TAG = "[MainActivity]";

    Activity activity;
    SongAdapter songAdapter;
    SongsManager songsManager = new SongsManager();
    MediaPlayer mp;

    // Songs list
    public ArrayList<SongModel> songsList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        activity = MainActivity.this;


        mp = new MediaPlayer();


        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager(activity);
        final ArrayList<SongModel> songsListData = songsManager.songList;


        this.songsList = plm.getAllSongs();


        for (int i = 0; i < songsListData.size(); i++) {
            SongModel song = songsListData.get(i);
            songsListData.add(song);
        }


        songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this,songsList,this);
        setListAdapter(songAdapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseClicked(int position){

          //Todo-- Add code you want to perform on Pause clicked with   specific position

    }
    @Override
    public onPlayClicked(int position){
         //Todo-- Add code you want to perform on Play clicked with   specific position
    }
}
```

Comment: See my changes on activity, I am getting nullpointer in OnMouseListner and tell me where i am wrong in this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43e3700bc0292623cf71208a41eeae61

Comment: Please check the edit code...I have added the activity code too.

Comment: Excellent...you save my time...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this when you want to set the image src from a ListView item to something else when the ListView item is tapped.

Use `view` parameter of `onItemClick` method to change `ImageView` of selected row:

```
@Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
   ImageView selectedImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.buckysImage);    
   selectedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);                 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass onclick listener to your adapter and set click listener to your image view.

And when you set your adapter from your activity just simply create new click listener as you passing params into your methods.